# What is the relationship between the PWM duty cycle input and the angular displacement and RPM of a DC motor?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor

If possible, could someone point me to some resources explaining these relationships? It would also be helpful if the resource discusses non-linearities such as dead-zones in terms PWM duty cycle vs. angular displacement for example.

Comment: Higher the PWM duty cycle, the higher the RPM. Everything else will depend on the motor make up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PWM frequency is high enough in relation to motor inductance, the behavior is the same as a DC voltage proportional to the duty cycle and the supply voltage.

Ideally this results in a torque proportional to the difference between that voltage and the back-EMF. Non-ideally there is some friction and windage loss.

The back-EMF, in turn is proportional to the RPM.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you provide me with some resources for further reading?

Comment: As a free resource, Microchip has a bunch of application notes and other materials, obviously aimed at supporting their MCU families.

Comment: Thanks again, do these resources explain the theory behind this? If not, could you suggest other resources that do?